# Shortcuts for Terminal for running a Java Program

Tags: shortcut-keys, java

I wrote a java program first time on Linux.

This is where my program `Test.java` is located:

`Desktop`> `APCS` (folder)> `Chapter5` (folder) > `Test.java`

I know that to compile I have to type `javac Test.java` and to run "java Test".

Before that, I have to type `cd Desktop`, `cd APCS`, `cd Chapter5`.

Is there any short way to navigate to `Test.java`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways to shorten the time it takes to go down multiple directories:

- You can go down multiple levels at a time, so you can type `cd Desktop/APCS/Chapter5`
- Pressing TAB while typing a directory or file name will automatically complete the rest of the filename for you. So if you are in your home folder and need to `cd` to your desktop, you can type the first two or three letters of Desktop and press tab to automatically complete it

If you need to compile and run your program a lot, make a shell script on your desktop or somewhere else with:

```
javac ~/Desktop/APCS/Chapter5/Test.java
java ~/Desktop/APCS/Chapter5/Test
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the full path.

Try using these commands:

```
javac ~/Desktop/APCS/Chapter5/Test.java
java ~/Desktop/APCS/Chapter5/Test
```

(This assumes the compiled output is in a filename named `Test` in the same directory)

Ultimately, though, you'll have to retype the path and change it accordingly for when the path changes.